# Path finding in a highly dynamic world

Tags: artificial-intelligence, collision-detection, path-finding

I am working on a simple soccer simulation, I am using potential fields for collision avoidance more specifically following technique,

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-antigrav/

only obstacles on the field are other players and they are constantly moving. Problem is it works if I assign really big push force to the characters since characters move at speed it takes some time to change direction but this has few drawbacks with such a high gravity I can never position an npc to grab the ball cause there is always some force pushing me around.

I though I could solve this by assigning pulling force to the ball but that actually made it worse. nps would go to the ball, ball starts pulling which makes npc push the ball it goes into a loop until npc crashes to a wall.

How I've implemented this is, I have a vector that would steer me towards my target then I add to that all gravitational forces acting on the npc and steer towards that direction.

Basically I am wondering what kind of improvements I can make? my current problem is not hitting other players precisely getting behind a ball without getting affected by other players.

Comment: It took millions of years of evolution for animals to be able to anticipate their way through a moving crowd. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that employing potential fields is the way to go here. If all players are directly between you and the ball, how do you get to it?

I'd be tempted to plot a straight line, then iteratively adjust the route for the position of other players, adjusting for their trajectories and — if you're *really* clever — anticipating changes in the same.

Comment: in theory gravitational push and my steering force can cancel each other but in practice this never happens it steers around the players. I do use a straight line that is my intended travel direction I let gravity adjust it.

Comment: @Hamza: That's handy, but I can't understand how it happens. If you don't understand either, then I suggest there's a problem. :)

Comment: @Hamza: I meant iteratively as in "go through each player", re-calculating the route every tick or so. You can pick one that will not lead your NPC into a corner or a dead end. // By contrast, you're picking one dumb route, then letting it be bent non-intelligently by basic physical factors as your character progresses along the route. If the initial route was severely flawed, then this will not work. // You should try to use information on movement of all players _ahead of time_ to pick the route that will be best _throughout_ the traversal period.

Comment: since everyone is moving that perfect alignment never happens, just a small change in position and you get pulled around the obstacle.

Comment: @tomarak: it is a soccer sim, I don't understand how I can pick a better route shortest route is the straight line that I am picking. there are no walls or obstacles other than the player on the field.

Comment: @Hamza: Have you ever played football? If you are a football player and your technique consists of always running directly at the ball, you're not going to score many goals. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put some kind of limit as to the area of effect that another player's gravity well will have.  Limit it to a small radius around that player so that when you're clear of other players, there are no forces acting on your character.  You could also diminish the collision avoidance force when you're near the ball, reasoning that players care less about not hitting each other when it's time to kick the ball.